# how to delete files of listview from menuInflater

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm creating an app in which I can search for files and delete them from the SDCard. Everything works, except I'm not able to delete files which are checked in the `ListView`.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); 

    viewholder = new ViewHolder();

    viewholder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    viewholder.texview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    viewholder.texview.setText(modelItems.get(position));

    viewholder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);



    viewholder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                if (((CheckBox) p1).isChecked())
                {
                    checkBoxState[position] = true;
                    filepath = modelItems.get(position);
                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxState[position] = false;
                }
            }
        });
    return convertView;
}
```

How can I delete files which are selected in `ListView` and also update the `ListView`?

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.select_all:
            adapter.selectAll();
            return true;

        case R.id.deselect:
            adapter.unSelectAll();
            return true;

        case R.id.delete:
            adapter.delete();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Here is the deleted code which I tried, which changes should I apply here?

```
  public void delete()
{
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    for (int i=0;i < checkBoxState.length;i++)
    {
        if (checkBoxState[i] == true)
        {
            File f = new File(path + "/" + filepath);
            if (f != null && f.exists())
            {
                f.delete();
                modelItems.remove(modelItems.get(i));
            }
        }

    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: create a list. Everytime  checkbox is checked, add file path to list. When user confirms to delete, loop the list to get all the file paths, delete them one by one. Dont forget to remove item from list when unchecked

Comment: I tried but my code is not working :(

Comment: what is happening? last selected item deleted?

Comment: No, it's still there

Comment: what is `filepath = modelItems.get(position);` file name or complete path? Any exceptions?

Comment: It's String value for holding filename i guess, i think there is a mistake, how can i add complete path

Comment: try logging `f.getAbsolutePath()` after file initialization, and make sure that is the right path. Debug the app with proper breakpoints

Comment: At the line File f = new File() it returning same path again and again

Comment: Is it the correct (valid) path?

Comment: Yes, but it only returns first selected file path again and again

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        View view = listview.getChildAt(i);
                        CheckBox dateChk = view.findViewById(R.id.chkDate);

                        if(dateChk.isChecked())
                            {
                               File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + arrayList.get(i).getfilename());
                                  if (f != null && f.exists())
                                    {
                                       f.delete();
                                    }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Can't access listview because it's in another class

Comment: put this code inside activity class menuInflater delete click event try it.i am sure done it.

Comment: Not working, getfilename is unknown method for string class

Comment: put your file name there

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class

```
ArrayList<String> selectedFiles; // outside getView

public void resetSelectedItems()
{
    selectedFiles.clear();
}
```

Inside `getView`

```
viewholder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View p1)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            if (((CheckBox) p1).isChecked())
            {
                checkBoxState[position] = true;
                filepath = modelItems.get(position);
                selectedFiles.add(filepath);
            }
            else
            {
                checkBoxState[position] = false;
                if(selectedFiles.contains(modelItems.get(position)){
                     selectedFiles.remove(modelItems.get(position));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and delete function as

```
 public void delete()
 {
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    for (int i=0;i < selectedFiles.size();i++)
    {
       File f = new File(selectedFiles.get(i)+ "/" + filepath);
       if (f != null && f.exists())
       {
            f.delete();
            modelItems.remove(modelItems.get(i));
        }
    }
    resetSelectedItems();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Try this. I hope you have EXTERNAL_STORAGE read and write permissions. And don't forget to **initialize `selectedFiles`** in adapter's constructor.

Comment: What is adapter in delete method? Is it custom adapter object?

Comment: your delete is in adapter?

Comment: Edited answer on the assumption taht, delete method is in your adapter class

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it from onMenuItemSelected

Comment: App crashed when i tried to select checkbox with an exception FATAL EXCEPTION Null pointer exception

Comment: I can't use adapter.resetSelectedItems(); in this class because customadapter class object is created in another class and after removing that line exception is solved but file isn't deleted.

Comment: Try logging file.getAbsolutePath() now, after file initialization

Comment: And make sure selected files are in the same path

Comment: I need to scan sdcard again recursively so changed my code a bit, but it crashed at delete code

Comment: can you share crash log?

Comment: There is no any error showing in log, I think scanning all folder recursively taking too much time that's why my app is crashing.How can I make that process fast?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is almost solved now only one thing is remaining that i can't pass the file path, my code deleting all the file that contains the searched string 
Here are changes i have made

```
enter code here
public void delete()
{
    for (int i=0;i < selectedFiles.size();i++)
    {
        String s= selectedFiles.get(i);
        Log.d("selectedFiles.get(i)",""+s);
        searchFileForDelete(s);     
        modelItems.remove(s);
    }
    resetSelectedItems();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void displayDirectory(File dir)
{
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) 
    {
        allfiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            displayDirectory(file);
            allfiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

}


public void searchFileForDelete(String substring)
{
    File f = new File(path);
    displayDirectory(f);
    String searchString = substring;
    for(int i=0;i<allfiles.size();i++)
    {
        String tempVal = allfiles.get(i);

        if(tempVal.contains(searchString))
        {               
            Log.d("tempVal",""+tempVal);
            File dlt = new File(tempVal);
            if(dlt!=null && dlt.exists())
            {
                dlt.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```